# relation between casting and structural typing in Typescript

Tags: typescript, structural-typing

This is a question about *structural typing* in Typescript.

#### Example

The toy example is as following:

```
const onChange1 = (e: Event) => { this.x = (e.target as HTMLElement).innerText }

const onChange2 = (e: {target: HTMLElement}) => { this.x = e.target.innerText }
```

#### What I know:

`Event` has `target: EventTarget` which has no property we want.

We know we are dealing with Element.

So in `onChange1` we use `as` to *type casting* it into `HTMLElement` type.

In `onChange2` it has `{target: HTMLElement}` inline type and using it amount to say that it only accept value having `target:HTMElement`.

---

#### Question

We had to do type casting to make onChange1 work,  while to work in case 2 we just declare our desired type without casting.

I'm confused -- `onChange2` should not pass type checking.
This is impossible in `Scala` which also has *structural typing*.
Isn't `Typescript` type safe language ?

Comment: `onChange1` and `onChange2` have different types.  I'm not sure why you think `onChange2` shouldn't pass type checking.  Where?  Can you make a [mcve] that demonstrates what you're talking about?  As it stands `this` doesn't seem to refer to anything.